How to call native C++ function with variadic arguments from C# using managed C++ (C++/CLI)?
Example:
I have C++ function declared as
 void FunctionA(...);
or
 FunctionB(va_list args);
How can I create C++/CLI wrapper so I can call those functions from C#?
Thanks
[UPDATE]
I have a native C++ template function
std::string NativeFunction(const char* list, T var1, Types... var2)

and corresponding macro
#define NativeMacro(msg, ...)  NativeFunction(#__VA_ARGS__ ## ", TRACE", __VA_ARGS__, TRACE)

I have the native C++ source code available, but rather not modify it. (If it is not possible to do it without modifying the native C++ code let's also discuss this solution).
I need a managed C++ (C++\CLI) wrapper so I can call the NativeFunction and/or NativeMacro from C#.
I tried using va_list, ... array<> but could not get it working.

You can have a C++/CLI function with variable argment list (see: Variable Argument Lists (...) (C++/CLI)), but I am not sure how/if it can then be forwared to native C++.

This question is similar to: What is the proper PInvoke signature for a function that takes var args?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Renat Thanks for pointing to the __arglist, but as I tested it only works with PInvoke and I need a solution for managed C++ (C++/CLI). Will update the question. Thanks anyway.

@wohlstad Yes, I tested that, but don't know how to call it from C#.
